# How to protect and unprotect single byte memory?

Tags: c, linux, mprotect

I know that mprotect is used to protect a whole memory page. Can anyone please tell me if there is a way to protect and unportect a single memory byte?

Comment: No, there isn't. The granularity is the page size, so you will have to protect a full page.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Just like using an integer to store a single boolean in uses 32 bits to store only 1 -- of course it works, but it gets inefficient with larger numbers of bits.

Answer (score 0):

Protect how?  If you are looking for protection against concurrent reads/right a pthread_mutex_t is what you are looking for.

http://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/manual/pthread_mutex_init.html

As mentioned in the comments, mprotect is used for full pages.